# Zeromq : How to send message longer than 30 character from python client to c++ server

Tags: c++, python, client, zeromq

I made a C++ server and python client which sends message together.

It seems like there is no problem on sending very long messages to python client from server but python client cannot send or c++ server does not receive message longer than 30 characters.

I know there is 30 character limit on small messages but HOW to send long message?

Comment: Can you post the bit of C++ code that handles the `recv()`? This is just over TCP/IP? I'm not sure what 30 character limit you're referring to... unless I'm totally missing something.

Comment: 30 characters is the limit for a VSM (very small message) that fits inside the zmq_msg_t struct.  But in general, there is no size limit on messages, as their data is just a `void*` and size.  I regularly send many-MB messages from Python to C and back.  There's nothing special about the Python bindings in this regard.  A code sample would be helpful for identifying your bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would assume the C++ has something equivalent, but at least in the python bindings there's a [send_multipart](http://zeromq.github.com/pyzmq/api/generated/zmq.core.socket.html#zmq.core.socket.Socket.send_multipart) and the corresponding [recv_multipart](http://zeromq.github.com/pyzmq/api/generated/zmq.core.socket.html#zmq.core.socket.Socket.recv_multipart) which should probably be used by default unless you know for a fact that you will never receive or broadcast messages bigger than whatever the framesize is(probably never happens).